# KQL: Exclude partial string from results using Sentinel Watchlists

Tags: kql, azure-sentinel, partial-matches

Using a watchlist to store domains to be excluded from this query. However unable to filter out the domains on the watchlist from the results.
Dealing with SMTPS. The Watchlist items do not contain the "@" symbol.

Watchlist Example:

| SearchKey | SMPT |
| --- | --- |
| hotmail.com | hotmail.com |
| gmail.com | gmail.com |

```
EmailAttachmentInfo
| join kind=inner _GetWatchlist('FriendsList') on $left.SenderFromAddress == $right.Email
//| join kind=leftanti _GetWatchlist('SMTP-exceptions') on $left.RecipientEmailAddress == $right.SearchKey
|summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by SHA256, RecipientEmailAddress 
|project SenderFromAddress, TimeGenerated, RecipientEmailAddress, FileName, SHA256, FileType, FileSize, RecipientObjectId
//| where not(RecipientEmailAddress has_any(_GetWatchlist('SMTP-exceptions')))
```

The comments are my attempts. These would/should work if what was needed wasn't a partial match.

Comment: The 2nd option (has_any) should have work for you, but only because in your example *SearchKey* equals *SMPT*. In the future please keep your example as simple as possible and provide a sample data for all involved tables & functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let _GetWatchlist = (name:string)
{
    datatable(SearchKey:string, SMPT:string)
    [
        "hotmail-com" ,"hotmail.com"
       ,"gmail-com"   ,"gmail.com"
    ]
    | where name == 'SMTP-exceptions'
};
let t = datatable(RecipientEmailAddress:string)
[
   ,"eliza.doolittle@hotmail.com"
   ,"beetlejuicebeetlejuice@beetlejuice.com"
   ,"maximus@gmail.com"
   ,"pinocchio@hotmail.com"
   ,"dorothy@notkansasanymore.com"
];
t
| where not(RecipientEmailAddress has_any((_GetWatchlist('SMTP-exceptions') | project SMPT)))
```

Comment: This line alone solved the problem.

| where not(RecipientEmailAddress has_any((_GetWatchlist('SMTP-exceptions') | project SMTP)))

Comment: I know :-) All the the rest of the code is an ad-hoc sample data and implementation of the function.